# Provided dependencies can only be jars

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an android projct in Android Studio, was all previously working the last time I used it, however, I've upgraded Android Studio and now I am getting a weird problem.

In the error output in Android Studio I have the following:

```
Warning: Project MyApp: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.google.android.gms:play-services.6.5.87 is an Android Library
Warning: Project MyApp: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.MyCompany.MyLibrary:aar:1.0 is an Android Library.
```

Below is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'android'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.MyCompany.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.MyCompany:CritiMon:1.0'
    compile 'com.MyCompany:Library:1.1'
    provided 'com.MyCompany:MyLibrary:1.0'
    compile 'com.MyCompany:NavigationDrawerManager:2.1'
    provided 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Comment: Change `provided` to `compile`. I can't speak for your library, but `play-services` is not "provided", from the Gradle standpoint, on any device AFAIK.

Comment: Yea that's correct, not sure why it suddenly doesn't work. I've had it like that for ages.

Comment: I just had the same problem with the recyclerview lib, but I only updated the version of the Android Gradle plugin. It looks like it's not working anymore with version 1.1.x.

Comment: I posted suggestion to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076270/provided-gradle-dependency-is-aar-not-jar/36635527#36635527

Answer (score 13):

Your provided dependencies can only be jars, your custom Android Libraries in your project should be compile at build time.

Change this:

```
provided 'com.MyCompany:MyLibrary:1.0'
provided 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.MyCompany:MyLibrary:1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Comment: how can you make them used to compile but still optional?

Answer (score 11):

I restore the Android Plugin Version from 1.1.0 to 1.0.0 and it work.

You can do it by the order:

1. Right-click your project.
2. Select `Open Module Settings`
3. Select `Project`
4. Change the `Android Plugin Version`

Comment: That is a solution. But downgrading isn't really a fix, just a workaround.

Comment: You are right. See the release notes: [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Comment: Thanks, was a great help at a desperate time. Cheers!